# LinkButton in GridView dynamically

Tags: c#, gridview, linkbutton

I am binding a grid with DataTable, there are two columns which I am using, and the result in GridView1 is is,

```
HostelName | HostelCode
  Alpha    |     1
  Bravo    |     2
  Charlie  |     3
```

Now I want this HostelCode as a LinkButton for all the records which are in database, so that I can do further actions while clicking LinkButton.
Any help ??

I am using this code, but its not working,

```
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            LinkButton lb = new LinkButton();
            lb = (LinkButton)GridView1.SelectedRow.FindControl("lbtnSelect");
            lb.Text = dt.Rows[1].ToString();
        }
```

lbtnSelect is the ID of my linkbutton.

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: When do you run the code (`for (int i ...`) you are showing?

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
this is the error which I am getting @MuneebZulfiqar on 2nd line inside for loop.

Comment: @Markus I am running this code after filling DataTable and before binding this to GridView1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use link button in template field of gridview and Eval function to bind value in linkbutton in aspx page.

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvrecords" CssClass="Gridview" DataKeyNames="HostelCode"
            AutoGenerateColumns="false" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#7779AF" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White"
            OnRowDataBound="gvrecords_RowDataBound">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="HostelName" HeaderText="Hostel Name" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Hostel Code">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtn" runat="server" OnClick="lnkbtn_Click" Text='<%#Eval("HostelCode")'></asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: This works, but now I want to get the value of HostelCode which I have selected, because I need that selected value for further processing.

Comment: generate RowCommand event of GridView and in that you can get Hostel code.

Answer (score 0):

**ASPX CODE**

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvrecords" CssClass="Gridview" DataKeyNames="HostelCode"
            AutoGenerateColumns="false" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#7779AF" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White"
            OnRowDataBound="gvrecords_RowDataBound">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="HostelName" HeaderText="Hostel Name" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Hostel Code">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtn" runat="server" OnClick="lnkbtn_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

**CS CODE**

```
public partial class Tests : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            BindHostelDetails();
        }
    }
    protected void BindHostelDetails()
    {
        gvrecords.DataSource = DBData();
        gvrecords.DataBind();
    }
    protected void gvrecords_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            string HostelCode = Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "HostelCode"));
            LinkButton lnkbtnresult = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("lnkbtn");
            lnkbtnresult.Text = HostelCode;
        }
    }
    protected void lnkbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {

        LinkButton lnkbtn = sender as LinkButton;
        GridViewRow gvrow = lnkbtn.NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
        int hostelcode = Convert.ToInt32(gvrecords.DataKeys[gvrow.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
        string HostelName = gvrow.Cells[0].Text;    
        Response.Write("<script> alert('" + "Hostel Name :"+ HostelName +" Hostel Code :"+ hostelcode + "'); </script>");
    }
    List<DTest> DBData()
    {
        List<DTest> _Dt = new List<DTest>();
        _Dt.Add(new DTest { HostelName = "Alpha", HostelCode = "1" });
        _Dt.Add(new DTest { HostelName = "Bravo", HostelCode = "2" });
        _Dt.Add(new DTest { HostelName = "Charlie", HostelCode = "3" });
        return _Dt;
    }
}
public class DTest
{
    public string HostelName { get; set; }
    public string HostelCode { get; set; }
}
```